# Use sed to rewrite line of file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I want to be able to make sure that one line of a configuration file contains an appended path .

The line in the file looks something like:

```
checkedpaths=${myapp.base}/lib
```

If it doesn't have ${myapp.base}/bin on the line, I want to append the line to something like:

```
checkedpaths=${myapp.base}/lib,${myapp.base}/bin
```

There could be any number of other paths on the line.
${myapp.base} is already defined in the file, and no need to worry what it expands to.

I was trying to do this using standard shell script commands.
I think with sed that I may be able to do it more compactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with an `awk` script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{printf "%s", $0}
     !/\$\{myapp\.base\}\/bin/ {printf "%s", ",${myapp.base}/bin"}
     {print ""}' input_file > output_file
```

**Input:**

```
checkedpaths=${myapp.base}/lib
checkedpaths=${myapp.base}/bin,someotherstuff
```

**Output:**

```
checkedpaths=${myapp.base}/lib,${myapp.base}/bin
checkedpaths=${myapp.base}/bin,someotherstuff
```

**Explanation:**

- `awk`: invoke the awk command
- `'...'`: everything enclosed by the single quotes will be run by awk
- `{printf "%s", $0}`: for each line, print it as is, but do not terminate with newline
- `!/\$\{myapp\.base\}\/bin/ {printf ",${myapp.base}/bin"}`: if the pattern `${myapp.base}/bin` is matched anywhere on the current line, then print `,${myapp.base}/bin` (since we didn't terminate the line with a newline in the last step, this appends it to the end of the same line.)
- `{print ""}`: Now terminate the currently line with a newline char, regardless of whether the pattern was matched or not.
- `input_file > output_file`: use `input_file` as input; redirect output to `output_file`

Comment: Consider lines containing `${myapp.base}/binary`

Comment: Also, "." is an RE metacharacter so you'd need to escape that and you might also need to escape { and } depending on your awk version. Finally, use print "" instead of printf "\n" and the synposis for printf is `printf fmt, text` so use that instead of `printf text` in case any formating characters sneak into "text".

Comment: @EdMorton: thanks Ed, your code reviews are always super helpful to my learning.

Comment: np, happy to help and you always take my feedback in the spirit it's intended, i.e. to be constructive.

Comment: Thanks.  I used a close variant to this.  I also need to add to the conditional a check that checkedpaths= was at the start of the line.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do:

```
sed '/checkedpaths/{ \@${myapp.base}/bin@!s@$@,${myapp.base}/bin@ }'
```

This does not replace the content of the file: either redirect or use `-i`.  Also, this is not particularly robust and will fail to append text to a line that contains `${myapp.base}/binary`, but that's pretty easy to fix if it is an issue.

Comment: Would I need to use something other than sed to determine if ${myapp.base}/binary is already on the line?  Or can it somehow be build into the search criteria -- it would fail if it found it there and not do anything?

Comment: @GeorgeHernando - Is it an issue?

Comment: You can use sed, but you need to change the first check inside the `{` to prevent the short match.  Unfortunately, sed does not allow `[,$]` to mean "comma or end of line", so you need to do ugly things like: `\@[:,]${myapp.base}/bin\(,\|$\)@`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{print $0 (/\$\{myapp\.base\}\/bin(,|$)/ ? "" : "${myapp.base}/bin")}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `sed` but only `bash`, you could use :

```
if [[ $myvar != *tobeappended* ]]
then
    myvar=$myvar,tobeappended
fi
```

Comment: Most definitely. But since the question stated "was trying to do this using standard shell script commands [...]", I figured it would still be interesting for the OP to get at least one non-`sed` answer.